# Can't get except statement to print when forcing an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I can't seem to get my except statement to print when forcing an error.

```
PLANT_DATA = { 'daisy': 'diasy.csv',
              'rose': 'rose.csv',
              'cucumber': 'cucumber.csv' }

def filters():
    print('Let\'s explore some plant data')
    while True:
        plant = input("Would you like to see data for Cucumber, Daisy or Rose plants?").lower()
        if plant in PLANT_DATA.keys():
            try:
                print("Looks like you want to hear about {} plants!".format(plant)) 
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not a valid plant! Please try again.")

filters()
```

Comment: No repro. You can only _force_ an error in this code by entering a key from `PLANT_DATA` (`daisy`, `rose` or `cucumber`) and then it will throw `NameError`, which you don't catch. If you don't enter one of the aforementioned answers then it will just keep asking the same question.

Comment: I am forcing the error by by the input function. Example by putting in an integer or wrong plant not in the dictionary

Comment: No you're not. `if plant in PLANT_DATA.keys():` being `True` is the only way to get to your `try`/`except` so you must first-of-all enter some value that actually exists as a key to even get to your exception handler. I already explained how

Comment: Are you coming from a different programming language btw?

Comment: No, first time programmer. I think I understand you now though.

Comment: Fair play. I note a mismatch in how you're trying to throw the exception (which makes sense and is a deliberate `NameError`, though you didn't know the specific error name) and missing the `if` logic that stopped you getting to that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Yes:

```
print("Looks like you want to hear about {} plants!".format(city))
```

Is almost certainly going to throw an error, because `city` is not defined. But it's not *guaranteed* to throw an error because you have a logical blocker:

```
if plant in PLANT_DATA.keys():
```

If this is not `True`, you never get to your exception handler. It will just got back to another loop of the outer `while` loop. To get past this, you need to enter a valid `key` from `PLANT_DATA`. So, `daisy`, `rose` or `cucumber` as inputs will clear this check and make sure that you throw an error. However, it will be a `NameError`, not a `ValueError`.

It's very easy to throw an error; `int('hi')` would throw an error, for example, but it won't fit into the context of what you're trying to at all. So I think you're correct in keeping the example as it is, without changing the logic; you're wandering into [python testing](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/09/improve-your-python-understanding-unit-testing/) (and that's not a bad thing)

Answer (score 0):

The following line;

```
if plant in PLANT_DATA.keys():
```

Checks if the provided key exists in the dictionary. You never reach your except clause as you're already performing the check earlier in code. This is why whenever you enter an incorrect value, it prompts you for the question again.

If you need to print an error, try this.

```
if plant not in PLANT_DATA.keys(): 
    print("That is not a valid plant! Please try again.")

else:
    print("Looks like you want to hear about {} plants!".format(city))
```